# Microsoft Excel: PowerPivot 2010: Linking Access Databases

Tags: powerpivot

I've read up on PowerPivot help and researched the video's online. To the best of my knowledge it seems you can only import Microsoft Access Database Tables through PowerPivot. It doesn't seem to be the logical means of accessing Access Tables. I have a large Access Database that I would like to access through PowerPivot to create Pivot Tables to summarise my data in different ways. Is there any way of linking to a Microsoft Access Database instead of actually importing the tables. I'm currently storing my data in Access mdb format as I'm storing spatial data as well from ArcGIS.

Regards

PeterW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of the source, PowerPivot will always "physically" import the data.  This is necessary in order to take advantage of the [xVelocity Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh922900.aspx) which allows PowerPivot to work its magic (read: perform complex analysis over millions and millions of rows in seconds).

But even though the data is physically imported, PowerPivot retains the connection to the source via the connection definition:

[image]

...so in that sense, it is still linked "logically" to the source.  The caveat is that changes to the source won't be immediately reflected in PowerPivot.  You have to refresh the PowerPivot source:

[image]